# Excel:Return cell index for the first occurrence of a value against a set of values in same sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I just got this work, where I have some 75000 values I need to check against this data I have. The work I have at hand is like this.

1. I have been given a text file with a set of values which I have to check against this Excel sheet.
2. I have to return the row number of the first occurrence and preferably the cell index as well

so i came up with this.. that i would paste the values from the text file in the same Excel sheet as i have done in the image adjacent to the red marker and in the adjacent column apply some "magical" formula, which you guys I hope will help me out with" ,which will return the index from the range of values you see on the upper side of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your red mark is in C80000 and no hidden columns, maybe the following copied down as necessary would suit:

in C80000: `=IFERROR(MATCH(B80000,$B$1:$B$75000,0),"")`
in D80000: `=IF(ISNUMBER(C80000),"B"&C80000,"")`

Not tested by me and will not work in early versions of Excel.